# Why the error between the measured data and model data is not minimizing in Python?

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization, scipy, mse

I want to fit the non-linear experimental data with the model function by estimating some parameters in the function. The model function I have is: `Vocv+a*It+(b*It)*[1-exp^(-x/b*c)]` where a,b and c are the parameters needs to be estimated/adjusted in order to fit with the experimental data.

> P.s:: I am working on Parameter Optimization of a Battery in Python.

Before applying the optimization I have tested the function, by manually adjusting the values of a,b,c to fit with experimental data and the result is following:

[image]

However, after applying the optimization in which I have set initial values as found out by trail and error manually it still can not optimize further.

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from scipy.optimize import differential_evolution
import warnings
Data = pd.read_excel(r'/home/Documents/Data.xlsx')
Vocv = Data.loc[:,'Vocv']
It = Data.loc[:, 'It']
t = Data.loc[:, 'Tt']
Ex_voltage = Data.loc[:, 'Experimental_Voltage(v)']
Ex_time = Data.loc[:, 'Experimental_Time(s)']
X = np.array([Vocv, It, t])

'''Befor optimization-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------'''
def voltage_1(X, a0, a1, a2):    
    return (X[0]+(a0*X[1])+(a1*X[1])*(1-np.exp(-1/(a1*a2))*X[2]))

a0 = 4.500e-07  ##### Initial Values guessed by trial and error

a1 = 3e-07      ##### Initial Values guessed by trial and error

a2 = 0.02       ##### Initial Values guessed by trial and error



errors = (Ex_voltage - voltage_1(X, a0, a1, a2))
square = np.sum(errors**2)

plt.plot(t, voltage_1(X, a0, a1, a2))
plt.plot(Ex_time, Ex_voltage, label='Experimental Data') 
   
'''---------After applying Optimization-------------------------------------------------------------------
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~Minimize method to estimate battery parameter-------------------------------------------------------------'''
''' Need to estimate value of a0,a1,a2,a3 in such a way that it minimize the errors as low as possible'''
def sumOfSquaredError(parameterTuple):
    warnings.filterwarnings("ignore") # do not print warnings by genetic algorithm
    val = voltage_1(X, *parameterTuple)
    return np.sum((Ex_voltage - val) ** 2.0)

def generate_Initial_Parameters():
    # min and max used for bounds
    maxX = 100

    parameterBounds = []
    parameterBounds.append([4.500e-07, maxX]) # search bounds for R0
    parameterBounds.append([3e-07, maxX]) # search bounds for R1
    parameterBounds.append([0.02, 0.06]) # search bounds for C1

    # "seed" the numpy random number generator for repeatable results
    result = differential_evolution(sumOfSquaredError, parameterBounds, seed=2)
    return result.x

# generate initial parameter values
geneticParameters = generate_Initial_Parameters()

def SumsqErrors(A):
    y = (X[0]+(A[0]*X[1])+(A[1]*X[1])*(1-np.exp(-1/(A[1]*A[2]))*X[2]))
    errors = Ex_voltage - y
    return np.sum(errors**2)
bestparameters = minimize(SumsqErrors, geneticParameters, method="trust-constr")
print(bestparameters)

bestA = bestparameters.x
n2 = len(t)
y2 = np.empty(n2)
for i in range(n2):
    y2[i] = voltage_1((Vocv[i], It[i], t[i]), bestA[0], bestA[1],bestA[2])
    
font = {'size'   : 15}
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rc('font',**font)
t2 = Ex_time
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(t,y2, c='r', marker = 'o')
plt.plot(t2,Ex_voltage, c='k', marker = '>')
plt.plot(t, voltage_1(X, a0, a1, a2), label='Before_Optimization')
plt.legend(loc = 'best')
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel(r'Time $(s) $')
plt.ylabel(r'Voltage $(V)$')
```

The output is following:

[image]

```
a0 = 4.50022988e-07
a1 = 3.00017973e-07
a2 = 0.02
```

Basically the same value as initial value given; it is not optimizing to give me an optimal solution. I am very confused that what is wrong in my code, unable to understand because of very less experience in programming.

The expected result is: The error should be as less as possible between experimental/measured data and model/simulated data to give me an optimal solution.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DataScienceSE. I don't know this particular genetic learning library so I can't really help with the implementation, but I'd suggest a few general directions to debug: (1) run a simple toy example to make sure there's no bug in the code (e.g. from a tutorial or some known problem) ; (2) the range of values is crucial, are you sure that there is a better solution in this range? ; (3) I see that the seed is set to 2, make sure to try different seeds (preferably don't set seed to anything, at least before obtaining decent results); (4) I'm surprised not to see any particular ...

Comment: ... parameter for the genetic search, no number of iterations or anything (but as I said I don't know this specific library).

Comment: Thank you so much replying @Erwan . Could you suggest some other solution for this problem like can it be solved by sklearn library.

Comment: Sorry I can't recommend any library: personally when I've used genetic learning I implemented my own algorithm, this way I'm able to control every part of the process and check that things are working the way they're supposed to. It's not very difficult but of course you'd have to be comfortable doing the programming. If you plan to do it with this library it's certainly possible, but you should try to understand how it works before using it with your main problem: did you try some simpler case with a known solution? And also do you understand and can control the parameters of the algorithm?